# Does Blitzcrank / Nautilus Q stop a channeled Fiddle?

Tags: league-of-legends

If Fiddle was the start his ultimate (the period before the teleport) and Blitz or Nautilus used a Q on him, would it cancel Fiddle's ultimate, using the cooldown?

Comment: I am 99% sure that anything that moves the champion, knockbacks, toss ups and pulls will cancel the spell channel. I am not positive though so I don't want to submit as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once Fiddlesticks has finished casting Crowstorm, has teleported and the spell effect has started, nothing can stop it - you're screwed.

However, if you can grab Fiddle while he's *channelling*, before the spell actually goes off, you will cancel his ultimate.  Silencing him during this channel also works.

Comment: Totally screwed. Best surprise party ever. <3 Fiddles!

Comment: Not even silence or stun ?

Comment: He's not actually casting anything at that point, he just has an effect running on him - so silencing him doesn't help.  Stunning him won't stop the effect but will keep him from moving, making him easier to escape from.

Comment: More generally, whatever may be channelled, silencing/bumping/stunning/forcibly moving/squirelling will abort the cast.

Comment: Yep, now waiting for a video of a Blitzcrank that trolls his team by pulling an ulted Fiddlesticks onto his team so the Fiddlesticks gets a pentakill with the assist of Blitzcrank